# Map string as int-array to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a textbox in my view with the following values:

"1, 3, 5, 8" or

"1; 3; 5; 8".

Is it possible to map those values as an int-array to a controller method?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUsers(int[] values)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? I use the standard route settings of asp.net MVC 3.

Comment: No, sorry, it's a HTTP post.

Comment: Are u trying to pass the array to Action Method Parameter ?

Comment: Yes, it should map to int[] values.
string[] values would also be okay...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**URL should look like this. In JQuery, you can prepare the URL based upon TextBox values.**

**http://abc.com/ControllerName/ActionName/?id=1&id=2**

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int[] id)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom model binder. Add a class, say `ArrayIntModelBinder` and implement [IModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) interface:

```cs
public class ArrayIntModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        string values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("values").AttemptedValue;
        return Array.ConvertAll(values.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }), int.Parse);
    }
}
```

In the view you have your textbox:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="values"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

and apply the new model binder to your action

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUsers([ModelBinder(typeof(ArrayIntModelBinder))]int[] values)
{
    ...
}
```

or you can register it as global in the `Application_Start`.

Of course this version of model binder is very simplified just to give you the idea. You have to provide some validation of the input string at least. Hope this helps.